# select com order by

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela simples com apenas um campo texto, sem campo `auto increment` e índices

```
CREATE TABLE teste (Nome varchar(30) NOT NULL)
```

Inseri nessa tabela as informações na seguinte ordem:

```
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('C')
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('D')
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('B')
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('A')
```

Se eu fizer um select ordenado por nome vai me retornar a ordenação por nome, ok.

```
select * from teste order by nome - resultado: A,B,C,D
```

O que preciso fazer é um select que me retorne a ordem que foi inserido, ou seja, que o resultado esperado é C,D,B,A.

É possível obter esse resultado numa tabela simples como essa?
Existe algum índice oculto que possa fazer esse `order by`?

Comment: acho que a melhor forma seria criar um campo com `auto increment` e ordenar por esse campo

Comment: Você é DBA?, se sim, coloque um campo auto increment, será  melhor para o desempenho do seu banco do que fazer uma mágica com o order by

Comment: uma tabela sem chave primária é uma ideia ruim, ainda que não faça uso "direto" dela. Crie um campo com uma chave numérica e identity e ordene por ela, assim como sugerido pelo @Sorack, sem essa informação não irá saber a ordem que foram inseridos. Ainda assim eu sugiro que tenha um campo data, com valor default `getdate()`. A semente do identity pode ser alterada, o que irá bagunçar sua busca caso isso aconteça

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 4):

> É possível obter esse resultado numa tabela simples como essa?

Não

> Existe algum índice oculto que possa fazer esse order by?

Não

---

A partir do `SQL Server 2007` você pode utilizar uma coluna [`IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017). Altere sua tabela e adicione uma coluna com sequência:

```
ALTER TABLE teste
  ADD sequencia INT IDENTITY;
```

E selecione utilizando o `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT t.Nome
  FROM tabela t
 ORDER BY t.sequencia;
```

> [`IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Cria uma coluna de identidade em uma tabela. Esta propriedade é usada com as instruções `CREATE TABLE` e `ALTER TABLE` Transact-SQL.

---

Como o [**Ricardo Pontual**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57220/ricardo-pontual) observou:

> Só uma observação: usar o campo `IDENTITY` com o claro propósito de saber a ordem de inserção dos registros pode falhar se a semente do `IDENTITY` for alterada ou reiniciada por exemplo, o que é raro alguém fazer, mas pode acontecer.

Comment: só uma observação: usar o campo identity com o **claro propósito** de saber a ordem de inserção dos registros pode falhar se a semente do identity for alterada ou reiniciada por exemplo, o que é raro alguém fazer, mas pode acontecer. Um campo com a data/hora seria mais seguro desse ponto de vista

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu cogitei o uso de um `DATETIME`, porém o uso de recurso é maior, se a data do servidor sofrer alteração a coluna será prejudicada também e, apesar da chance de acontecer ser extremamente baixa devido a granularidade do tempo, existe a possibilidade de inserção simultânea. Um `IDENTITY` não tem os mesmos problemas. Eu vou adicionar a sua observação a resposta, OK?

Comment: Perfeito, a melhor solução por conta de performance é essa mesma de um campo int como identity da sua resposta, só coloquei como observação porque às vezes as pessoas podem mudar o identity,e ai pode bagunçar a ordenação